# Created Chatbot on OpenFire but getting error

Tags: java, android, xmpp, openfire

I am trying to make chatbot plugin for openfire.But when i run plugin on openfire then i am getting below error:-

```js
2016.10.28 18: 04: 21 org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginManager - Error loading plugin: C: \Program Files(x86)\ Openfire\ plugins\ hospitalbot
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServerInfo.getName() Ljava / lang / String;
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.botz.BotzConnection.login(BotzConnection.java: 319)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.botz.BotzConnection.login(BotzConnection.java: 272)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.plugin.ChatBot.initializePlugin(ChatBot.java: 75)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginManager.loadPlugin(PluginManager.java: 447)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginManager.access$300(PluginManager.java: 68)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginManager$PluginMonitor.run(PluginManager.java: 1037)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.container.PluginManager.installPlugin(PluginManager.java: 176)
at org.jivesoftware.openfire.admin.plugin_002dadmin_jsp._jspService(plugin_002dadmin_jsp.java: 180)
```

I have copied this plugin from below link :-
https://community.igniterealtime.org/docs/DOC-1130

I am getting error in below file :-

```js
package org.jivesoftware.openfire.botz;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import org.jivesoftware.openfire.Connection;
import org.jivesoftware.openfire.SessionManager;
import org.jivesoftware.openfire.SessionPacketRouter;
import org.jivesoftware.openfire.XMPPServer;
import org.jivesoftware.openfire.roster.Roster;
import org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.AuthToken;
import org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.UnauthorizedException;
import org.jivesoftware.openfire.net.VirtualConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.openfire.session.ClientSession;
import org.jivesoftware.openfire.session.LocalClientSession;
import org.jivesoftware.openfire.spi.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.openfire.user.UserAlreadyExistsException;
import org.jivesoftware.openfire.user.UserNotFoundException;
import org.jivesoftware.util.Log;
import org.jivesoftware.util.StringUtils;
import org.xmpp.packet.JID;
import org.xmpp.packet.Packet;
import org.xmpp.packet.StreamError;

/**
 * The objective of BotzConnection class is to create a robot/bot application as
 * an internal user of the main XMPP server. The class's login methods performs
 * the necessary (virtual) connection to the server. The bot can login as an
 * anonymous or a real user.
 *
 * <p>
 * The class's object uses a BotzPacketReceiver object passed to it via one of
 * it's constructors or via calls to
 * {@link #setPacketReceiver(BotzPacketReceiver)} method to receive packets from
 * other XMPP entities to the bot. The bot can reply to these packets with
 * {@link #sendPacket(Packet)} method. Thus, a class that wants to handle bot
 * packets must implement {@link BotzPacketReceiver} class.
 *
 * <p>
 * Below is a sample parrot bot code snippet illustrating how to use
 * BotzConnection and BotzPacketReceiver:
 *
 * <blockquote>
 *
 * <pre>
 * *
 * * BotzPacketReceiver packetReceiver = new BotzPacketReceiver() {
 * *     BotzConnection bot;
 * *     public void initialize(BotzConnection bot) { this.bot = bot; }
 * *     public void processIncoming(Packet packet) {
 * *   if (packet instanceof Message) {
 * *       packet.setTo(packet.getFrom());
 * *       bot.sendPacket(packet);
 * *   }
 * *  }
 * *     public void processIncomingRaw(String rawText) {};
 * *  public void terminate() {};
 * * };
 * *
 * * BotzConnection bot = new BotzConnection(packetReceiver);
 * * try {
 * *     bot.login(&quot;MyUsername&quot;);
 * *     Presence presence = new Presence();
 * *     presence.setStatus(&quot;Online&quot;);
 * *     bot.sendPacket(presence);
 * * } catch (Exception e) {
 * * }
 * *
 * </pre>
 *
 * </blockquote>
 *
 * @author Aznidin Zainuddin
 * @see BotzPacketReceiver
 */
public class BotzConnection extends VirtualConnection {
  /**
   * The packet receiver object that will handle receiving of packets.
   */
  private BotzPacketReceiver packetReceiver;
  /**
   * Holds the initialization state of the packet receiver.
   */
  private boolean initPacketReceiver;
  /**
   * Holds the session for the bot.
   */
  private LocalClientSession localClientSession;

  private Roster roster;

  private JID jid;
  /**
   * Creates a new instance of BotzConnection.
   */
  public BotzConnection() {}

  /**
   * Creates a new instance of BotzConnection with the specified packet
   * receiver.
   *
   * <p>
   * When login is attempted with an instance created with this constructor,
   * the packetReceiver traps incoming packets and texts as soon as the bot
   * logs on.
   *
   * @param packetReceiver
   *            BotzConnection packetReceiver
   */
  public BotzConnection(BotzPacketReceiver packetReceiver) {
    this.packetReceiver = packetReceiver;
  }


  public LocalClientSession getLocalClientSession() {
    return localClientSession;
  }

  public Roster getRoster() {
    return roster;
  }

  /**
   * The method will be implicitly called by the server when the bot's
   * connection is (virtually) closed. The method terminates the packet
   * receiver.
   */
  @
  Override
  public void closeVirtualConnection() {
    if (packetReceiver != null && initPacketReceiver) {
      packetReceiver.terminate();
      initPacketReceiver = false;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Calls to this method is made by the server to deliver packets to the bot.
   * This method will in turn call
   * {@link BotzPacketReceiver#processIncoming(Packet)} of the packet receiver
   * associated with the bot.
   *
   * @param packet
   *            XMPP packet
   * @throws UnauthorizedException
   *             When packets could not be delivered due to authorization
   *             problem.
   */
  public void deliver(Packet packet) throws UnauthorizedException {
    if (packetReceiver == null)
      return;
    packetReceiver.processIncoming(packet);
  }

  /**
   * Calls to this method is made by the server to deliver raw text to the
   * bot. This method will in turn call
   * {@link BotzPacketReceiver#processIncomingRaw(String)} of the packet
   * receiver associated with the bot.
   *
   * @param text
   *            The text string delivered to the bot.
   */
  public void deliverRawText(String text) {
    if (packetReceiver == null)
      return;
    packetReceiver.processIncomingRaw(text);
  }

  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   *
   * @see org.jivesoftware.openfire.Connection#getAddress()
   */
  //@Override
  public byte[] getAddress() throws UnknownHostException {
    return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getAddress();
  }

  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   *
   * @see org.jivesoftware.openfire.Connection#getHostAddress()
   */
  //@Override
  public String getHostAddress() throws UnknownHostException {
    return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
  }

  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   *
   * @see org.jivesoftware.openfire.Connection#getHostName()
   */
  //@Override
  public String getHostName() throws UnknownHostException {
    return InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
  }

  /**
   * Get the bot's packet receiver
   *
   * @return BotzPacketReceiver packetReceiver
   */
  public BotzPacketReceiver getPacketReceiver() {
    return packetReceiver;
  }

  /**
   * Get the resource portion of the bot's JID.
   *
   * @return Resource portion of the bot's JID.
   */
  public String getResource() {
    if (localClientSession == null)
      return null;
    return localClientSession.getAddress().getResource();
  }

  /**
   * Get the node's portion of the bot's JID.
   *
   * @return Node portion of the bot's JID.
   */
  public String getUsername() {
    if (localClientSession == null)
      return null;
    return localClientSession.getAddress().getNode();
  }

  /**
   * Get the node's portion of the bot's JID.
   *
   * @return Node portion of the bot's JID.
   */
  public JID getIdentity() {
    if (localClientSession == null)
      return null;
    return localClientSession.getAddress();
  }

  /**
   * Check whether the bot session is still active.
   *
   * @return <tt>true</tt> if the bot is still active, <tt>false</tt>
   *         otherwise.
   */
  public boolean isLoggedOn() {
    return !isClosed();
  }

  /**
   * Login to the XMPP server as an anonymous user. This method creates a
   * virtual connection to the XMPP server and establish a user session. If
   * the packet receiver is already defined, initialize it.
   *
   * @throws BotzSessionAlreadyExistsException
   *             If the users session already exists.
   */
  public void login() throws BotzSessionAlreadyExistsException {
    if (isClosed())
      throw new BotzSessionAlreadyExistsException();
    localClientSession = (LocalClientSession) SessionManager.getInstance().getSession(jid);
    localClientSession.setAnonymousAuth();
    if (packetReceiver != null) {
      packetReceiver.initialize(this);
      initPacketReceiver = true;
    }
    return;
  }

  /**
   * A convenient way to login. It uses the default "Botz" as the JID resource
   * and auto create the user if it doesn't exist.
   *
   * @param username
   *            The username to login with.
   * @throws BotzSessionAlreadyExistsException
   *             If the bot's session already exists.
   * @throws UserNotFoundException
   *             If it fails to create the user.
   *
   * @see #login(String, String, boolean)
   */
  public void login(String username)
  throws BotzSessionAlreadyExistsException, UserNotFoundException {
    login(username, "Botz", true);
  }

  /**
   * A convenient way to login. It auto create the user if it doesn't exist.
   *
   * @param username
   *            The username to login with.
   * @param resource
   *            The resource the user will bind to.
   * @throws BotzSessionAlreadyExistsException
   *             If the bot's session already exists.
   * @throws UserNotFoundException
   *             If it fails to create the user.
   *
   * @see #login(String, String, boolean)
   */
  public void login(String username, String resource)
  throws BotzSessionAlreadyExistsException, UserNotFoundException {
    login(username, resource, true);
  }

  /**
   * Login to the XMPP server and establish a non-anonymous user session using
   * the given username and resource. When <tt>createIfNotExist</tt> is
   * <tt>true</tt>, a new user with the username will be created and stored
   * in the database if it does not exist. When <tt>false</tt>, and the
   * user does not exist, the method will not attempt the login. Whenever
   * there's an error, the bot will not login.
   *
   * @param username
   *            Username to login with.
   * @param resource
   *            The resource the user will bind to.
   * @param createIfNotExist
   *            When specified as <tt>true</tt>, a new user will be created
   *            and stored in the database if it does not exist.
   * @throws BotzSessionAlreadyExistsException
   *             If the bot's session already exists.
   * @throws UserNotFoundException
   *             If it fails to create the user.
   */
  public void login(String username, String resource, boolean createIfNotExist)
  throws BotzSessionAlreadyExistsException, UserNotFoundException {
    if (isClosed())
      throw new BotzSessionAlreadyExistsException();

    jid = new JID(username.toLowerCase(), XMPPServer.getInstance().getServerInfo().getXMPPDomain(), resource);
    ClientSession oldSession = XMPPServer.getInstance().getRoutingTable()
      .getClientRoute(jid);

    // Check for session conflict
    if (oldSession != null) {
      try {
        oldSession.incrementConflictCount();
        int conflictLimit = SessionManager.getInstance()
          .getConflictKickLimit();
        if (conflictLimit != SessionManager.NEVER_KICK) {
          // Kick out the old connection that is conflicting with the
          // new one
          StreamError error = new StreamError(
            StreamError.Condition.conflict);
          oldSession.deliverRawText(error.toXML());
          oldSession.close();
        } else
          throw new BotzSessionAlreadyExistsException();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.error("Error during login", e);
      }
    }

    if (!XMPPServer.getInstance().getUserManager().isRegisteredUser(
      jid.getNode())) {
      if (createIfNotExist) {
        try {
          // Bot doesn't care of whatever password it is.
          XMPPServer.getInstance().getUserManager().createUser(
            jid.getNode(), StringUtils.randomString(15), null,
            null);
        } catch (UserAlreadyExistsException e) {
          // Ignore
        }
      } else {
        throw new UserNotFoundException();
      }
    }

    localClientSession = (LocalClientSession) SessionManager.getInstance().getSession(jid);
    localClientSession.setAuthToken(new AuthToken(jid.getNode()), jid
      .getResource());
    if (packetReceiver != null) {
      packetReceiver.initialize(this);
      initPacketReceiver = true;
    }

    this.roster = XMPPServer.getInstance().getRosterManager().getRoster(username);

  }

  /**
   * Logout the bot and destroy the active session. This method need not be
   * called explicitly unless, for example, when callers need to refresh the
   * assign a different username or resource (re-login).
   */
  public void logout() {
    close();
  }

  /**
   * Send a packet out to an XMPP entity. The packet must be one of
   * <message/>, <iq/> or <presence/>. Callers need not specify the
   * <tt>from</tt> attribute inside the packet because it will be
   * automatically inserted with/replaced by the bot's real JID.
   *
   * @param packet
   *            The packet to send.
   */
  public void sendPacket(Packet packet) {
    if (isClosed())
      throw new IllegalStateException("No valid session");
    SessionPacketRouter router = new SessionPacketRouter(localClientSession);
    router.route(packet);
  }

  /**
   * Assign a packet receiver ({@link BotzPacketReceiver}) object that will
   * receive packets to the bot. The method can be called repeatedly if
   * necessary to dynamically change different packet receivers during a
   * login. If the previous packet receiver is in an initialized state during
   * this call, it will be terminated; and the new packet receiver will be
   * initialized.
   *
   * <p>
   * If the previous packetReceiver is the same with the new one, this method
   * will ignore the assignment.
   *
   * @param packetReceiver
   *            The packetReceiver object
   */
  public void setPacketReceiver(BotzPacketReceiver packetReceiver) {
    if (this.packetReceiver == packetReceiver)
      return;
    if (this.packetReceiver != null && initPacketReceiver) {
      this.packetReceiver.terminate();
      initPacketReceiver = false;
    }
    this.packetReceiver = packetReceiver;
    if (!isClosed()) {
      this.packetReceiver.initialize(this);
      initPacketReceiver = true;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Calls to this method is made by the server to notify about server
   * shutdown to the bot.
   */
  public void systemShutdown() {
    close();
  }

  @
  Override
  public ConnectionConfiguration getConfiguration() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
  }
}
```

Can any one please help me out as i am newb in openfire.

Comment: Which version of Openfire you are currently using in which you tried to install the plugin? and secondly from above link, did you download the jar file of plugin or you took the source code and built it by yourself?

Comment: I am using openfire 4.0.3  version . And from above link i have downloaded source code and build myself.

Comment: I think bot has not been customized for newer versions as you can see in trailing last post in that discussions that it doesn't work for anyone.But you can always use smack api to create your own bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think bot has not been customized for newer versions as you can see in trailing last posts in that discussions that it doesn't work for anyone.But you can always use [smack api](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/) to create your own bot.

1. Create a bot id.
2. Create a Java App and connect to Openfire using Smack
3. Use a business logic once you receive the chats and reply to the same.

Comment: I am doing same now. But i am stuck on second point. I am not able to connect to openfire using Smack.

Comment: Good to know. Have a nice time ahead with bots.